# Spring boot GCP PUBSUB Consumer application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

Can anyone share spring boot GCP PUBSUB subscriber application example, which keep running util externally killed (not rest api)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, our [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.3.0/reference/html/index.html#subscribe-methods) instructs users to provide their own `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean named `pubsubSubscriberThreadPool` with non-daemon threads to keep the application running. However, this seems to have stopped working and is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1182).

In the meantime, you can provide a scheduled no-op process as a workaround:

```
  @Scheduled (fixedRate = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  public void ensureApplicationRuns() {
    // do nothing, or log message
  }
```